# Boost.Asio IPv6 Why bind error?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I want to use IPv6 using boost asio in Linux (fedora).

NIC is

```
ifconfig -a
em1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.16.109  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.16.255
        inet6 fe80::215:17ff:fe62:d168  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:17:62:d1:68  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 59516986  bytes 7105720351 (6.6 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 5015310  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8680244  bytes 1666346667 (1.5 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 18  memory 0xb8820000-b8840000
```

and IPv6 udp bind code is...

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        const char* ip_address_string = "fe80::215:17ff:fe62:d168";
        // const char* ip_address_string = "::1";  // It's OK
        boost::asio::ip::address my_address = boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(ip_address_string);
        udp::endpoint local_endpoint(my_address, 15060);

        udp my_protocol = udp::v6();
        udp::socket sock(io_service);
        sock.open(my_protocol);
        sock.bind(local_endpoint);

        std::cout << "ip:" << local_endpoint.address().to_string() << std::endl;
        // -*/

    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Binding of v6 loopback address is ok, but specific ("fe80::215:17ff:fe62:d168") address is binding error.

exception error is "bind: Invalid argument".

Why binding error?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might not have permission to access the external network adaptor.

Perhaps (parts of)

- ipv6 have been disabled (even though the adaptor is obviously capable and configured)
- /proc is not mounted (are you in a restricted environment, like a `chroot` jail?);
- the ip address is actually different - this is a bit of a lame one, since you'll have checked this a bazillion times, but I felt I should at least mention it

Now, try in environments with fewer restrictions (e.g. outside virtualization containers, as root...).

If this doesn't get you the information you need consider using `strace` or `ltrace` to see which syscalls are failing.

---

Your code is ok, I've tested it to work on Linux and MSVC (substituting my NIC addresses)

Comment: Your comments are thanks a lot for me. I will check ipv6 module in my Linux machine again.